# How to get the indices of the float numbers in the array after sorting with numpy partition

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

I was trying to sort the array list using `np.partition` but it sorts the list wrongly. I think the reason is the float numbers in the list. How can I sort the array list consisting float numbers using `np.partition` and get the indices of the elements?

```
x = np.array([0.056669, 0.019477, 0.06245, 0., 0.019524, 0.058592, 0.05847, 0.078317, 0.09599])
print(np.partition(x, 1)[0:9])
```

Result is here:

```
[ 0.        0.019477  0.06245   0.056669  0.019524  0.058592  0.05847
  0.078317  0.09599 ]
```

The desired output is here:

```
[3 1 4 0 6 5 2 7 8]
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation? what's your expected output? does `np.partition` meet your needs?

Comment: To get indices, use `np.argpartition`.

Comment: `np.argsort(x)`?

Comment: @Divakar That solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`np.partition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html) just "partitions" your elements, it doesn't do a full sort. It's for "getting the lowest/highest `k` elements"-like operations. From the docs:

> #### numpy.partition(a, kth, axis=-1, kind='introselect', order=None)
>
> Return a partitioned copy of an array.
>
> Creates a copy of the array with its elements rearranged in such a way that the value of the element in k-th position is in the position it would be in a sorted array. All elements smaller than the k-th element are moved before this element and all equal or greater are moved behind it. **The ordering of the elements in the two partitions is undefined.**

If you want to `sort` the complete array, you should use [`np.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html).

There are several numpy functions that give you the indices instead of the values, these typically start with `arg*`, for example [`np.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html#numpy.argsort).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([0.056669, 0.019477, 0.06245, 0., 0.019524, 0.058592, 0.05847, 0.078317, 0.09599])

>>> np.partition(arr, 1)
array([ 0.      ,  0.019477,  0.06245 ,  0.056669,  0.019524,  0.058592,
        0.05847 ,  0.078317,  0.09599 ])
>>> np.argpartition(arr, 1)
array([3, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], dtype=int64)
>>> np.partition(arr, 7)
array([ 0.      ,  0.019524,  0.019477,  0.056669,  0.058592,  0.05847 ,
        0.06245 ,  0.078317,  0.09599 ])
>>> np.argpartition(arr, 7)
array([3, 4, 1, 0, 5, 6, 2, 7, 8], dtype=int64)

>>> np.sort(arr)
array([ 0.      ,  0.019477,  0.019524,  0.056669,  0.05847 ,  0.058592,
        0.06245 ,  0.078317,  0.09599 ])
>>> np.argsort(arr)
array([3, 1, 4, 0, 6, 5, 2, 7, 8], dtype=int64)
```